What is the maximum rated EV charger I can install and use here?
I have an old house which has had extensions progressively added over 100 years. I cannot wire any cables directly from my main circuit breaker to my garage. Ideally I would like to install a Type 2 EV charger to the circuit breaker that is already in my garage. Note - I will not be doing this myself, I am just looking for advice on what I should be expecting to hear when I contact a professional installer.
I am concerned because the circuit breaker in my garage is already behind 2 layers of MCBs so I dont know what current or KW charging capacity I should be expecting from the charger installed in my garage.
Hopefully the image is self explanatory with all relevant info (?).
What rated EV charger should I be installing, and how, if I want to maximise charging?


To add a charger or power consuming device, you need to know how much power the panels can handle and how much power you are consuming.  What is left is the size of the charger you can have.  Most people can get by with a small charger, charge over night, than need a big charger that charges in an hour.

The process @crip659 is talking about is a "load calculation", commonly spoken of on this site. You'll need a load calculation on each panel, to see if there is enough free space all the way up the chain. (Note, the code folks in your area may have a different name for it, but the idea is the same.)

Yeah, you're going to need to know what size the mains is and how much load is on the 'residential circuits' and 'lighting circuits'.

Tentatively, though, the C20 MCBs protecting the 6mm cable could almost certainly be 25A, probably 32A, possibly 40A. That probably lets you squeeze in a 16A 3~ charger (11kW), or unload one phase entirely and dedicate it to a 32A 1~ charger (7kW). We can more-or-less assume that the existing load is <20A per phase because breaker trips presumably haven't been an issue so far.

See also the many other answers tagged "ev-charging" for discussion of how much charger you need and how folks typically connect them up.

Your maximum will be the capacity of 6mm2 wire
or probably 32A.
"Wait! That's the maximum the Type 2/Mennekes/J3068 standard supports, and is ludicrously fast at 22 kW! How can an old house support that?"
Because your demanding requirements force us into very particular advanced tech which is capable of that. It's going to cost more and be tricky to acquire, but you have precluded all other possibilities.  And since we have the technology, we might as well use it to full effect.
Your service is fairly modest, and your charging plans extremely ambitious.  Also, you are unwilling to fund running cabling from the main service panel/consumer unit to the garage.  That forces us to use the existing feeders, which fortunately are 6mm2 and 32A even under the most conservative rules.  I don't know why they are 20 amp breakers - this is something you can address with the electrician to open up that pathway to at least 32A.  Whatever that is, that constitutes your charging limit.
The trick being the other loads in the house
And this is why we are forced into a particular technology - EVEMS.  This places "CT" current meters on the main supply wires from the utility.  It is monitoring the current draw of all loads in the house including EV charging.  It then communicates with the "charger" (which is not a charger at all) which then adjusts charge current dynamically to prevent the house's electric service from overloading.
Normally I would link Technology Connections' video about letting go of range anxiety and install a more modest system, but given the limitations of your house, I think we are forced into this technology. So we might as well make the most of it.  Note that high-power EV charging is by far the most demanding load a house will ever face. So it is also the most unforgiving to even the slightest flaw in an electrical installation. You have been warned.
Because of your "no cables" prohibition, we are forced into the Myenergi ZAPPI for the charging station, which calls this feature "Grid Limit".  This can partner with a power meter called the HARVI, which can communicate with the ZAPPI via radio link (solving your "cannot run a wire" problem).
Mind you, I have not kept up on the latest European product selection. It's possible someone else has an EVEMS capable station with radio link to its power meter.
The grid limit will need to be set to the MINIMA of your electric service from the utility, the capacity rating of every wire and circuit breaker and equipment enroute.
Most of your charging happens at night, when loads in the house are quiescent, so you will get full charging power.  At other times, you can increase EV charge rate by turning off the other loads in your house.
Phase balancing will help
If you followed the link I provided to Technology Connections' "What an EVSE is" video, Alec was incorrect that Europe doesn't use that. They certainly do use exactly the same technology, differing only in 2 additional phase wires being added. Indeed, American cars (e.g. brought over for US soldiers) will plug right into Type 2 Mennekes either with a Type 1 tether cord, or an adapter made of metal and plastic.
But here's the point: There are 3 phases, but only one CP wire indicating authorized amp draw.  This means that in the 3-phase Mennekes system with EVEMS, the signal must conform to the heaviest loaded phase.  If you have 32A electric supply, wish to deliver 32A to the car, and your three phase loadings are 0A / 2A / 21A, such that they have 32A / 30A / 11A of headroom, regrettably EVEMS must tell the car "you may only take 11A".
Thus, you should take care to see that single-phase loads likely to be used together are on different phases, so that in that same case, the three phase loadings are 8A / 7A / 6A for instance, providing 24A of headroom.

Thanks a lot. I think a DEFA Power and DEFA Balancer seem to do the same thing as the Zappi and Harvi but over wifi. https://www.defa.com/ev-charging/loadbalancing-with-defa-balancer/

Yeah, that should do it.  I'm cautious about WiFi anything because it may create dependencies. At extremes, we have the Emporia in North America where the meter talks to "The Cloud" and the EVSE talks to "The Cloud", and I'm really not a fan because it adds so many points of failure.

I do agree, I was planning on looking for a feature of the charger, i.e. on the Depa Power, which is that I can just manually set the power, so as to say doing manual load balancing if I had to face those other issues on occasion, and limit my overall problems.

@Attack68 You can always reduce charging further than the hardware allows, but check with your authority - I'm pretty sure the load balancing function must be automatic to comply with electrical codes. I.E. you can't have an installation where you could forget to manually reduce EV charge before you take a shower, and trip the main circuit breaker.  We call that "hanging it all on the main breaker" here, single point of failure.  That's even more critical in tiered subpanel arrangements.

6mm² is for circuits up to 55A. That's the max current you will be able to push into your car through the existing path. (or up to whatever breaker is present in the main panel protecting that run).
You may be able to upgrade the cable from the main panel all the way to the garage panel, that will increase the max current.
Any EVSE for domestic installation can be set to limit its current based on the breaker that feeds it, so the specific model doesn't matter as much.
There are smart EVSEs that use current sensors that attach to the feed of the panel to make that current-limiting dynamic. Though those usually are set to measure only a at a single point. In your case it seems best to make that measuring point single point the utility room panel.
With that dynamic current limiting you can maximize charge rate while not overloading the circuit.
Though you will want to check your car and cable to see if it can actually pull that many amps, either can be a bottleneck.

This might be dependant on region, but here in NZ 55A is higher than any of the acceptable current ratings for 6mm for 75 or 90C cable. 40A might be arguable but the 34A (ASNZS3008 table 13 column 15) rating for a 75C cable partially surrounded by thermal insulation would be the typical choice. The originally specified C20 MCB is very conservative unless it is completely surrounded by thermal insulation.

I do know that the NZ tables (3008.1.2:2017) are calculated using 30C ambient whereas the Australian version (3008.1.1:2017) uses 40C ambient, so that will cut capacity slightly. I can't find where OP is but the colour scheme suggests probably NZ/Aus.

Both cables between the breakers are a single cable 5 core running in conduit under the floor, in concrete, and then exposed on the wall, not in thermally insulated wall. Based in Sweden. While I can't find the exact tables it seems something like 44-49 Amps. I did also think the C20 MCB were also overly conservative in the first place. Not sure if this was done for load balancing with some of the other circuits, though.
